# Concatenating multiple .xls files with unknown number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, xls

Using Python, I want to merge all .xls files in a directory into one data frame and save that as a new concatenated .xls file. The .xls files will have an unknown number of columns and no consistent headers.

I've used other suggestions on this forum and ended up with this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)

files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(f for f in files_xls) # I dont understand what to add 
# in the parentheses here.
    df = df.append(data)
    df
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
File "<ipython-input-17-bb67a423cf40>", line 14, in <module>
  data = pd.read_excel(f for f in files_xls)

File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 170, in read_excel
  io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)

File "C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 229, in __init__
  raise ValueError('Must explicitly set engine if not passing in'

ValueError: Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this brother

```
df = []

for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(f) 
    df = df.append(data)

mydf = pd.concat(df, axis = 0)
```

Comment: you need to add your path, like `read_excel('P://myfolder' + f)`

Comment: Okay, I think the problem might be with the files I'm trying to work with. I made some test .xlsx files to try this out (with your filepath suggestion), and now I'm getting this error: 
  File "<ipython-input-10-457ba263105e>", line 15, in <module>
    df = df.append(data)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'